# find the number of rows in each partition using "HASH PARTITIONING" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, localhost, partitioning

I was reading a book about "SQL QUERIES" and in the section about "HASH method for partitioning" I found the query that I will post here. I tried to do that with my localhost running on "WAMPSERVER". this is the query:

```html
CREATE TABLE courses
( id_course INT NOT NULL,
course_name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
course_level ENUM('beginner', 'intermediate', 'advanced')
)
PARTITION BY HASH (id_course)
PARTITIONS 5 (PARTITION C1, PARTITION C2, PARTITION C3, PARTITION C4, PARTITION C5);
```

after that I inserted 10 rows in my table. here is the picture of table rows:

[image]

after that I tried to find out the number of rows that was located in each partition. the book suggested this query:

[image]

but the problem is that in the output of query in the book for the "partition_rowcount" column is not similar to me. I (just for information) explain that the book had 4 partitions and named them "H1 to H4". here is the output of book:

[image]

I want to know that what is the problem and why my output is different from book. I know that there are other queries to find the rows in each partition, but I can not understand the reason for this difference.

Comment: I have yet to find _any_ benefit of `HASH` partitionings.  Skip that chapter; won't ever need it.  Learn about `PARTITION BY RANGE()` but do not expect miracles from even that variant.

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?   `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';`

Comment: I am using mariaDB version 10.4.10 and mysql version 8.0.18

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a hex string which suggests something has gone wrong with the data types. This is explained in  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56642. Try explicitly casting the `count` to a string so it can concatenate with your other string normally:

```
Select concat("# of rows in H1",(cast count(*) as char)) partition_rowcount
From courses partition (c1)
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answering. but are you sure about the syntax? because it gives me a syntax error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(*) as char)) partition_rowcount

Comment: That bug report seems to blame Workbench, get the Question seems to be using the commandline tool (`mysql`).

Comment: I do not use mysql workbench. I am using mysql command-line.